# External HDMI monitor, Dell Inspiron 15 (7537)

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dell-inspiron

Since I bought it, my Dell Inspiron 15 (7537, with Nvidea GeForce GT750M graphics) was plugged into an old 1920x1200 24" monitor... until, recently, the (very-old) monitor spectacularly died - with a bang. The old set-up was good.

I've been looking for a replacement external monitor.  I want to run it to extend the laptop display (as I did with the old 1920x1200 display) but I am finding compatibility information *very* hard to come by.

Over the weekend, I managed to hook the laptop up to a 4K TV... it would drive it, but not simultaneously with the display in the laptop... and the frame rate when playing back a 1080p video was shockingly bad.  These glitches have persuaded me that I should not try to use a 4K  monitor for everyday work.

These days, large, new 1920x1200 displays are rare... I am trying to establish whether a WQHD (2560x1440) display, when connected to the Dell over HDMI, would provide me with a sensible refresh rate... while extending the display in the laptop.

Does anyone know if (or how I can find out if) my laptop will drive a WQHD display "properly" over HDMI, while also driving the internal 1080p panel?

Comment: The [GPU](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gt-750m/specifications) itself supports being connected to a monitor which supports *3840x2160*.  You are going to need to use `DisplayPort` to get the resolutions you want.  The specifications are very helpful.

Comment: The laptop has no DisplayPort socket, so DisplayPort is not an option.  The laptop drove the 4k TV @ 3840x2160 over HDMI, but it wouldn't drive the internal display simultaneously... and the screen refresh rates were sufficiently bad on the 4K, that it, IMHO, it wouldn't even be suitable for casual video playback.  I know it is perfect @ 1920x1200... but do not know where I stand at 2560x1440 - as I don't have access to a monitor of this specification to try.

Answer (score 1):

Having hit a dead-end trying to establish compatibility... I bought a Samsung S27D850T 27" WQHD monitor... and connected it over HDMI to the Dell 7537 over HDMI.  It displays 2560x1440 @60Hz without problems - even when extending the 1080p internal display.